# How to delete claims from b2c custom policy claims claims bag (claims collection)?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to remove all the claims from the claims bag, if a certain step/condition in my custom policy is reached, however I couldn't find any information about that. Then I tried to use the `NullClaim Transformation` for strings, but I couldn't find anything for numbers, booleans and dates. The working example for string is as follows

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="SetDisplayNameToNull" TransformationMethod="NullClaim">
 <OutputClaims>
   <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" TransformationClaimType="claim_to_null" />
 </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Should I just set dates to a really old date like 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z?

Should I just set booleans to true/false depending on their suitable default values?

If yes, how would I go about it, as I can see that I can get currentDateTime, but I am unable to find any documentation setting a specific date value to a date type claim, same goes for the boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003445#deleteclaims) to delete claims in a custom policy.

Comment: but that would require us to get the objectId first, which I don't have at the step I want to clear all the claims.

Comment: Sorry this deletes the claim from the directory.